# [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

Tags: php, composer, iis, iis-7

У меня есть настроенный сервер windows 2016 с ISS, вопрос кто смог победить эту проблему?
предложение proxy и проверку сети не предлагать, проверено на простом компьютере в этой же сети composer diagnose выдает все нормально

Comment: на простом компьютер в той же сети фаервол так же настроен? отключите попробуйте

Comment: Фаервол везде отключен, включен только на маршрутизаторе Mikrotik. И оба в одной сети.